# How to disable Handle Bar dragging in HighStock JS

Tags: highcharts

The highstock api for navigator.handles provides only parameters for background color and border color. My requirement is to disable the handle bar dragging and the range should be selected only via range selector menu. 
I read this post [Disabling Handlebars in HighStock charts navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125572/disabling-handlebars-in-highstock-charts-navigator)

But it does not serve my purpose. 
Is there a way where if I set the property as enabled: false, or enableDragging: false then it hides the handle bar thus disabling the dragging functionality for highstock handle bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it.. 
This is the coffeescript code for the same.

```
chart: 
       events:
          load: ->
             @handlebars = $('g').filter ->
               $(@).css('cursor') == 'e-resize'
             @handlebars.css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately it is not available, only solution mentioned by you.

You have ability to request your suggestion in our uservoice page http://highcharts.uservoice.com/